# Partition Formatting when installing Ubuntu along side Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

When I am installing Ubuntu onto my PC, I get the following message from the installer:

SCI3 (0,0,0) (sda)

The following partitions are going to be formatted:

partition #5 of SCI3 (0,0,0)(sda) as ext4

partition #6 of SCI3 (0,0,0)(sda) as swap

Some found what I was trying to ask unclear, I just wanted to know if it was safe to continue without harming any files on my SSD

EDIT: I ended up creating a new partition and installing Ubuntu onto that

Comment: So what?? this massage tells that partition SCI1 (0,0,0)(sda) and SCI1 (0,0,0)(sda) are going to format.It's realy unclear that what are you asking.

Comment: It looks like it is going to format partitions #5 and #6 as it probably has Windows as partitions 1-4 on the drive already.  You should be good to continue.

Answer (score 0):

This message appears to tell you that the whatever changes you have made to the disk partition for installing Ubuntu are finally going to be written to the disk. i. e. 
the disk will be formatted  and Ubuntu will be installed to it.

Comment: So if I continue with the installation, will it have any effect on existing windows files or would it wipe my SSD?

Comment: It depends on what disk partition you had selected? If you had selected free disk partition then there will be no problem with windows

Comment: I didnt select any disk partition, the installation did it automatically when I choose to install it alongside Windows 10

Comment: Then it won't wipe your data. Your windows file will be as it is after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Once I continue to the next step in the installation, I get an error that says

Comment: Failed to unmount partitions, how would I fix this?

Comment: Its better to choose "Something else" while selecting , and then choose any free partition to install Ubuntu.